# SAML endpoints don't match by using the roor dir

Tags: spring, spring-security, saml-2.0, spring-saml

In order to setup the SAML Context of my Service Provider, I'm using a configuration as follows:

```
// Provider of default SAML Context
@Bean
public SAMLContextProviderLB contextProvider() {
    SAMLContextProviderLB provider = new SAMLContextProviderLB();
    provider.setScheme("http");
    provider.setServerPort(8090);
    provider.setIncludeServerPortInRequestURL(true);
    provider.setServerName("localhost");
    provider.setContextPath("/");
    return provider;
}
```

It returns this error (there is just a "slash" not needed):

```
BaseSAMLMessageDecoder: SAML message intended destination endpoint 'http://localhost:8090/saml/SSO/alias/defaultAlias' did not match the recipient endpoint 'http://localhost:8090//saml/SSO/alias/defaultAlias'
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the `provider.setContextPath("/");` to `provider.setContextPath("");` or upgrade to 1.0.0.RELEASE which should be able to handle `"/"` correctly.

Comment: If I set provider.setContextPath("");, it returns an error at runtime.

Comment: You're using an old version.